# Separate /var partition is full due to apt archives and snaps

Tags: partitioning, package-management, disk-usage, snap

For my last Ubuntu 18.04 installation I used different partitions for `/home`, `/var`, `/root` etc. I made each partition greater than [recommended on the Ubuntu site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace). Everything is fine except for the `/var` partition, the recommended size is 2gb, I made mine 10gb. But within a month I am already getting messages that `/var` is full. Below is the result of running `sudo du -sch *` within the `/var` directory:

```
6,7M    backups
3,5G    cache
22M     crash
4,5G    lib
4,0K    local
0       lock
282M    log
16K     lost+found
4,0K    mail
4,0K    metrics
4,0K    opt
0       run
2,1M    snap
532K    spool
60K     tmp
8,3G    total
```

As you can see, the `cache` and `lib` directories are both already greater than the recommended `/var` size. Diving deeper into it, the main reasons are the following two directories:

```
3,9G    /var/lib/snapd/snaps
3,4G    /var/cache/apt/archives
```

Since snaps are quite new I guess the recommended size for `/var` does not take that into account.

So my question is, is the `/var` supposed to be this big?
If so, is there a safe way to resize my partitions? And is there an updated list of recommended partition sizes?

Comment: Only you can know how much space you need. And if you don't know it, it's okay, just use a single partition like most everyone else.

Comment: Any particular reason for a /var/ partition? That was all well and fine 20 years ago for a server but has never been for a desktop. "So my question is, is the /var supposed to be this big? " depends on usage. If you have mysql installed I would make it as large as possible if you keep to defaults. "And is there an updated list of recommended partition sizes?" No, very simple: current idea for a server is 1 / and nothing else. For a desktop you could go / and /home or /, /home with  no personal data and a personal data partition

Comment: @Rinzwind IMHO you are missing this particular case. Is it OK to have so big Snaps and APT cache? I checked my APT cache, it’s less than 100 KB on all my installations (twice 16.04 and one legacy 12.04 server) and I don’t use Snaps at all. Therefore having gigabytes there does not look normal to me.

Comment: Please try `sudo apt autoclean`, then check the size of `/var/cache/apt/archives` againg. Did it shrink significantly?

Comment: Also, take a look at [this Superuser question on cleaning out old snaps](https://superuser.com/questions/1310825/how-to-remove-old-version-of-installed-snaps). Do you have the same issue?

Comment: @fkraiem, @Rinzwind I don't need a separate partition for everything. I was going for a separate `/home` partition but then I got a bit enthusiastic and made all those other partitions as well.


@Melebius that is what I was trying to ask, thank you. Maybe something changed with 18.04 regarding what is stored in apt cache. 


@user535733 `sudo apt autoclean` did not change anything and I do not have the same issue regarding the cleaning out old snaps.


My solution: I am going to do a fresh install, was already thinking about doing that. Thanks for all the fast responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short script which will remove *all* old versions of snaps. This will only keep the current active version, which should recover you some disk space.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Removes old revisions of snaps
# CLOSE ALL SNAPS BEFORE RUNNING THIS
set -eu

snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' |
    while read snapname revision; do
        snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"
    done
```